# Best way to store large read only files to be accessed from multiple nodes

Tags: mysql, database, distributed-system

I have a small collection of files (less than 50), each file is about 4GB on average. I would like to have access to those files from different servers with as little latency as possible. How would you do it?

I was at first considering using some database but MySQL has limitations for files larger than 2GB.

The interface I'm looking for is really simple, I would like to publish files associating them with a key, and retrieve them using that key (like with redis but redis is for caching and has a max size of 512MB).

Comment: When you access the file, will you access the file as a whole (i.e., it's not something like a spreadsheet where you'll access it line by line and maybe jump around)?

Comment: As a whole, I need the entire file to be able to do anything with it.

Comment: if you're reading the entire file into memory before any processing, just use s3, or a cdn

Comment: You can use AWS s3 service, but as you mention you require low latency, can't you write your own service with few rest end point to get and upload.

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply trying to make a file available with as little latency as possible, you're looking for a CDN (content delivery network).

A CDN will place the file in multiple data centers around the world, and pull from the one that is physically closest to you, reducing latency as much as possible. CDNs are also optimized for retrieving and sending the file as quickly as possible. Once cached, the request won't even have to go to your server, it'll just be between the CDN and the end user.

The "key" can simply be the file name.

When it comes to a file, storing it as a file is (almost*) always going to be fastest. If you stored it in a DB, you'd only be adding additional latency for retrieving the file. It's always going to be at least a little bit slower than retrieving the file directly.

There are a number of CDNs out there. AWS' CloudFront is probably the most accessible and cheapest (at least initially). Akamai is probably the largest. MaxCDN is also a good option.

*: From a super-technical, pure-speed perspective of just retrieving the file, keeping it in memory (RAM) instead of storage (hard disk) will likely be faster which you can easily do with a database, though you can also do with custom file system drivers. While with a CDN, you lose this kind of low-level control, the benefits of a CDN having distributed servers is going to far more beneficial.

Comment: That will be the right solution one day I hope, but for now the application is too small, my servers are all in the same server room.

Comment: Using it from a file system will still be your best bet. If you want it to be a little faster, look at using a memory-based file system driver like `tmpfs` or `ramfs`, which will keep the file in memory. Note: Since it's in volatile memory, you'll have to keep a copy on the normal disk and copy it over on start-up.

Comment: Note too that you'll need a hefty amount of RAM on your servers, since you'll need at least as much as the OS, server, and file(s) take.

Answer (score 1):

The least latency would be to read the files from storage local to the app reading them. That would eliminate all network latency.

Then the task becomes how to keep copies of these files in sync across your different servers? I'd consider using [SyncThing](https://syncthing.net) to help with this.

Comment: That might do the trick ! Thanks ! Only downside is that I now need to maintain the location of the shared folder on all my servers.

Comment: @user3091275 It depends on your design, you can can externalize shared location information and expose an end point. But I am wondering can't you use solution like HDFS. I don't have experience with HDFS.